# VBA runtime 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having problems with a runtime 1004 error in VBA. I made a time registration tool, to measure time needed for specific actions. The weird thing is, that the code works perfectly 9 out of 10 times. Just that 1 out of 10 times it generates this runtime error. I cannot see what is causing this problem! I don't do anything different, yet it generates this error once in a while....

I did google and searched for this runtime error in combination with the Application.Ontime function, but I think its defined the way it should? Below is  the code, which I in turn found somewhere else on the net. There is a worksheet with commandbuttons (each for a specific activity) and once pressed, the StartTimer procedure is called (in a seperate module), press again and the StopTimer procedure (in a seperate module) is called. The error is (sometimes) generated in the StopTimer sub.

```
Public StartTime As Single
Public FinalTime As Single

Sub starttimer()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "nexttick"

End Sub

Sub Nexttick()
Sheet1.Range("y2").Value = Sheet1.Range("y2").Value + TimeValue("00:00:01")
starttimer
End Sub

Sub Stoptimer()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Home")
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "nexttick", , False
End With
    Sheets("Log").Range("c10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Format(Sheet1.Range("y2").Value, "h:mm:ss")

    Sheets("Home").Range("y2").Value = 0
End Sub
```

Its driving me nuts, especially since it works most of the time! Hope someone can help me out here :)

Thanks in advance!!

Bart

[Runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9PTb.jpg)

[Code thats generating the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw1V9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The *[Earliest Time]* value should be the same as originally set when scheduling the sub to `False`. Times are rounded to the nearest second which is why you're probably getting away with it sometimes. Seeing as you assign the value of the time to a cell, reference that cell instead of setting the time in your code:

```
Public StartTime As Single
Public FinalTime As Single

Sub starttimer()

StartTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime StartTime, "nexttick"

End Sub

Sub Nexttick()
Sheet1.Range("y2").Value = Sheet1.Range("y2").Value + TimeValue("00:00:01")
starttimer
End Sub

Sub Stoptimer()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Home")
Application.OnTime StartTime, "nexttick", , False
End With
    Sheets("Log").Range("c10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Format(Sheet1.Range("y2").Value, "h:mm:ss")

    Sheets("Home").Range("y2").Value = 0
End Sub
```

---

***Reference:*** [Application.OnTime Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx#Anchor_1)

> The value of *EarliestTime* is rounded to the closest second.
>
> Set *Schedule* to **false** to clear a procedure previously set with the same
> *Procedure* and *EarliestTime* values.

Comment: Thanks Macro Man! Hmmmm, the value in the cell (y2) is just the number of seconds, not the time the procedure started. Im not sure how the Earliest Time value can ever be the same, as "Now" as used to start the timer is quite different from the "Now" used to stop the timer (the difference between the two is stored in cell y2). So if this would be the case, the code should never work. I suspect you are correct, that the issue lies in the rounding... But referencing to the cell as in your example doesnt work unfortunately :(

Comment: Right; I had tried storing the time in that public variable as well. Somehow it results in the timer no longer counting second by second, but racing like a stopwatch. I then need to press break for the code to stop executing/looping. I then thought to use an IF statement to only update the StartTime variable if its 0 (i.e. new). This also fails to work.. :(